# Pipe find command output to ls command

Tags: linux, bash

Need to pipe find command output to ls command limiting `ls` command to a certain date. Sort of a filter by date modified but I want with the format of the `ls -lth --full-time`. The `find` command gives me last modified files within 365 days. 
But `ls` shows me everything.

```
find . -mtime -365 | ls -lth --full-time
```

find gives me:

```
$ find . -mtime -365
.
./en_mapp
./main.py
./file1.txt
./file2.csv
```

And ls -lth --full-time gives me:

```
$ ls -lth --full-time
total 8.0K
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  174 2020-09-21 10:59:26.858601430 +0200 main.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 2020-09-21 09:36:17.072137720 +0200 file2.csv
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K 2020-09-21 09:35:48.296169162 +0200 en_mapp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 2020-09-21 09:35:28.502502950 +0200 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0100 goldenfile.xls
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xargs` takes input from stdin and passes it as arguments to some command.

```
find . -mtime -365 | xargs ls -lth --full-time
# or better with no dirs and handle spaces and quotes in filename
find . -type f -mtime -365 | xargs -d '\n' ls -lth --full-time
# or better - handle newlines in filenames
find . -mtime -365 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lth --full-time
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the exec option of find with a terminating plus:

```
find . -mtime -365 -exec ls -lth --full-time '{}' +
```

Comment: Thanks, but the stdout result also gave me the goldenfile.xls in which I am trying to filter out as it was created in 2012. The first stdout part seemed ok. Is it possible to make so it won't print out the second parts so that only files and directories created/modified within 365days are shown.

Comment: Add the find option `-type f` to ignore directories.